# Laravel 5 This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: laravel, redirect

I'm working on a project on my local machine, and I use XAMPP for OSX

I used to be able to go to `localhost/projects` earlier today, but I don't know why am I keep getting the redirect loop now. When I take a look at the `Networks` tab in Chrome, it's redirecting back and forth between `projects` and `projects/`.

I've been trying to find redirect in my `ProjectsController`, but there's none. In fact, I'm using `Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController')`. Has anyone had this before? how do I solve it

I even tried to simply return a string in my controller

```
class ProjectsController extends controller {
    public function index()
    {
        return "index";
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Yet this still giving me redirect loop

It gives me status code `301` if that helps

Update ==
Here's my `route:list`
[image]

Comment: Can you please post your `route:list ` output?

Comment: I got  `[ErrorException]                                               
  The use statement with non-compound name 'Auth'` has no effect  

when I typed in `php artisan route:list`

Comment: @akad0 I just fixed the routing issue. I updated my post how the `route:list` look like

Comment: It seems your `/projects` route can be accessed via both `ProjectsController@index` and `ProjectsController@store`
Try to create a new controller and observe it's behavior, try to isolate the problem, because it is really not clear what can cause this.

Comment: That's resourceful controller.. @index accepts GET request, the other one accepts POST request

Comment: Have you configured any middleware that may cause the inf.loop?

Comment: I ran into this today. I had a route resource `images` mapped to an `ImageController`. It worked fine, until I created an `images` folder in my `public` directory. It created an infinite loop trying to handle the route and the folder existing.

Comment: Not sure, if it's the same as mine. I was having the too many redirect when I checked the log file, found this. "exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents". then changed the file permission for storage, and it's gone.